# Need help serializing multiple objects for caching to redis using C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, redis

I'm trying to figure out how to serialize multiple objects into one giant XML file to batch write it to a redis caching server. I know how to serialize data from each individual object but i need to batch all the data for all the objects into a single file and write it to redis.

QUESTION:
How to batch serialize multiple objects with multiple variables of data

Code generating each Object:

```
private void Initialize()
        {
            // runs through a list of 600ish skills and creates a call data generator for each skill
            foreach (var skill in _skills)
            {
                IFeedServiceAgent feedService = new FeedServiceAgent();
                feedService.Subscribe(skill.SkillNumber.ToString(), skill.CallServer);
                CallDataGenerator calldata = new CallDataGenerator(_callDataRepo, feedService);
                _callDataGenerators.Add(calldata);
                Console.WriteLine("Instance of " + skill.SkillNumber + " From Call Server " + skill.CallServer + " is preparing to start");
            }
        }
```

Each Generator is generating the same type of information but for a different skill on our call system. there are about 600 skills so 600 generators.

Example of data being generated:

```
_skillData.OldestCall = e.CmsData.Skill.OldestCall;
_skillData.AgentsStaffed = e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsStaffed;
_skillData.AgentsAuxed = e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsInAux;
_skillData.AgentsAvailable = e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsAvailable;
_skillData.AgentsOnCalls = e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsOnAcdCall;
_skillData.CallsWaitingInQueue = e.CmsData.Skill.InQueueInRing;
_skillData.Asa = e.CmsData.Skill.AnswerTimePerAcdCall;
_skillData.TimeSubmitted = DateTime.Now;
_skillData.EstimatedHoldTimeLow = e.CmsData.Skill.ExpectedWaitTimeLow;
_skillData.EstimatedHoldTimeMedium = e.CmsData.Skill.ExpectedWaitTimeMedium;
_skillData.EstimatedHoldTimeHigh = e.CmsData.Skill.ExpectedWaitTimeHigh;
_agentData.AgentName = item.AgName;
_agentData.AgentExtension = item.Extension;
_agentData.AgentAuxReason = item.AuxReasonDescription;
_agentData.AgentId = item.LoginId;
_agentData.AgentAcdState = item.WorkModeDirectionDescription;
_agentData.AgentTimeInState = DateTime.Now - item.DateTimeUpdated;
_agentData.TimeSubmitted = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: I considered creating a list and adding all of my Generators to a list but then it will only send the generator objects and none of the other objects that data is being assigned to by the generator, I.E. _agentData or _skillData

i think

Comment: i should correct myself. i know that is what i would like to do but it doesn't work because of objects that are contained inside of the generator objects do not get added to the xml

Comment: Objects have to be public to serializer otherwise they do no get added to xml.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like my original though of creating a list of my generators was correct. If you create a list and then serialize the list object it will include all of the public objects in it. Mine was not working initially because my objects inside of my generator were private.
Thank you to @jdweng for pointing this out!